# covariance matrix of X+Y and X-Y

Tags: probability, matrices, statistics, continuity, covariance

This question comes up in almost every past paper i do and is worth 10 marks and  just can't work it out...

Let $X$ and $Y$ have the joint pdf 
$$f(x,y)= \begin{cases} e^{-y},  \text{if} \  0 < x < y < \infty \\ 0,  \texttt{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

It first asks to find the marginal probability density functions of X and Y which i found to be

for x

$e^{-x}$

and for y

$y\cdot e^{-y}$

and i found these to not be independent.
It then asks to compute the covariance matrix of $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ and this i have no idea how to do.

Any help or hints will really be appreciated.

Comment: Shortcut: (X,Y)=(U(V+W),V+W) with (U,V,W) independent, U uniform on (0,1), V and W standard exponential. Easy computations ensue, using E(U)=1/2, E(U^2)=1/3, E(V)=E(W)=1 and E(V^2)=E(W^2)=2 and... independence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A=X+Y,B=X-Y$. You have to calculate 5 things: $E[A],E[B],E[A^2],E[B^2],E[AB]$. Each of these is an integral calculation; for example

$$E[AB]=\int_0^\infty \int_0^y (x+y)(x-y) e^{-y} dx dy.$$

Once you have these six quantities, calculate $\text{Var}(A)=E[A^2]-(E[A])^2,\text{Var}(B)=E[B^2]-(E[B])^2$, and $\text{Cov}(A,B)=E[AB]-E[A]E[B]$. Then the covariance matrix is

$$\begin{bmatrix} \text{Var}(A) & \text{Cov}(A,B) \\ \text{Cov}(A,B) & \text{Var}(B) . \end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: is there an another way of working out the expected values? as it takes a very long time and seems unrealistic to do in ten minutes in an exam

Comment: @jess It seems like you'll want to be pretty comfortable with integration by parts, or else allowed to use the fact that $\int_0^\infty x^n e^{-x} dx=n!$. But maybe there is some shortcut.